# How to order a recordest returned from a query by a field created within that same query (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

The Query (For this question I do not think that you need to see schema):

```
SELECT Agencies.AgencyName, (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Invoices.CostsTotal) FROM Invoices WHERE Contracts.ContractID = Invoices.ContractID) AS MaxInvoice
FROM Contracts 
LEFT JOIN Agencies ON Contracts.AgencyID = Agencies.AgencyID
ORDER BY MaxInvoice DESC;
```

How do we order the recordset returned from a query by a field created within that same query?

I have seen the function FIELDS(INDEX) ? But this does not exist in access? Also not sure that it would even work. In this instance I want to sort the recordset by the MaxInvoice field.

MS Access prompts me to enter a parameter value for MaxInvoice when I attempt to run this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write parent **SELECT** which wraps your current SELECT.
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT Agencies.AgencyName, 
 (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Invoices.CostsTotal) FROM Invoices 
 WHERE Contracts.ContractID = Invoices.ContractID) AS MaxInvoice
 FROM Contracts LEFT JOIN Agencies 
 ON Contracts.AgencyID = Agencies.AgencyID
) AS ContractsLargestInvoice
ORDER BY ContractsLargestInvoice.MaxInvoice DESC;
```

Comment: I think that Gordons answer is faster but yours worked without any tinkering! Thank you for response - great technique

Answer (score 2):

Most SQL dialects support the use of aliases in the `ORDER BY`.  But MS Access is further from SQL standards than most databases.

I would suggest you rewrite the query to move `Invoices` into the `FROM` clause -- using aggregation to get what you want:

```
SELECT a.AgencyName, MAX(i.CostsTotal) AS MaxInvoice
FROM (Contracts as c LEFT JOIN
     Agencies as a 
     ON c.AgencyID = a.AgencyID) LEFT JOIN
     Invoices as i
     ON i.ContractID = c.ContractID
GROUP BY a.AgencyName
ORDER BY MAX(i.CostsTotal) DESC;
```

It seems strange that you are using a `LEFT JOIN` and choosing a field from the *second* table and not the first.  This could be `NULL`.

Comment: Null gives a valuable piece of information! That agency has not received an invoice. I realize you do not see the schema, but on a hunch what should be used? I am trying to find the largest invoice for each agency. Each agency has x number of contracts. Each contract has one budget and x number of invoices. Just a example I am working on to develop skill set.

Comment: @learnAsWeGo . . . No, that is what `NULL` means if `agency` is the *first* table in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You are right, I needed to RIGHT JOIN on agencies. Thank you.